# Calling a Java program from a batch file with parameters containing Danish characters

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm calling a java program from a batch file with parameters to send an email, works fine except that the program won't accept Danish charters like `Æ`, `Ø`, `Å`, (see fromCompanyName).

Batch file:

```sh
set host="smtp.xyz.com"
set username="foo@bar.dk"
set password="Password42"
set FromCompanyName="Testing æøå"
set from="foo@bar.dk"
```

So right now the 'From' in the email looks like this: `Testing +å+ÿ+à`

If I use `echo æøå` in batch file output: `├ª├©├Ñ`
If I use `echo æøå` in a command prompt output: `æøå`

Comment: To begin with you should change your syntax to this ```Set "varName=strVal"```, instead of ```Set varName="strVal"```. Then when you use the variable, only add the doublequotes if needed, i.e. `"%varName%"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a text editor which is able to create unicode files
and make sure to create your batch file using this editor.

I assume (set) you are using a Windows operating system?
You may check out [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Open your Batch file and change the encoding using:

```
Encoding > Convert to UTF-8 (option without BOM)
```

Comment: Batch files should not generally be saved in Unicode, they should be saved in ANSI, and preferably using the same codepage as the users' default, I would assume in this case that would be codepage 865. That script could then, as needed define the codepage as 865 too. If the end users codepage is unknown, then in this case, I'd probably advise writing the script using ANSI codepage 1252

Comment: The OP asked for a solution on howto pass unicode characters (æøå) to a program using a batch file. using unicode then requires to store unicode within the batch file itself. I'm not suggesting to store batch files in unicode encoding.

Comment: in Notepad++ I changed Encoding →Character set → North European → OEM 865 Nordic and that did the trick.

Comment: EVi1b7wO, it appears that my advice was correct, and that your response does not currently answer the question at all. @JonasHansen, please do not mark an answer as accepted, when it is clearly not correct.

Comment: @EVi1b7wO, I was advised to use the correct code page in Notepad++ (already use Notepad++).
so I changed it to Encoding →Character set → North European → OEM 865 Nordic and that did the trick and put a comment on that. If I did something wrong - please advise so I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: Well, unicode is meant to be the standard for consistent encoding and representation of text across all language borders. I'm not a Windows user and advocate on the use of unicode to avoid situations like this. @Compo you could have posted an answer making your point, you didn't. Switching to utf-8 solves the problem as codepage 865 nordic does (being a subset).